# How to find item responsible for appearance in Theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I have spent a lot of time trying to find what item/color responsible for touch/focus color on DrawerLayout list.
I am using custom Navigation Drawer Implementation [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Now, I am using `MaterialDrawerTheme` from example.

I have following bug

[image]

Color changes when touch layout.
With using another available theme everything is ok (white color or transparent) `MaterialDrawerTheme.Light`

[image]

But in this case I have text,background colors and a lot of other thing not suitable for my app style.

Also it would be great to change it to the desired color.
I have looked into the source code chain , but I haven't found part responsible for this behavior.
Please help to find what attribute should I override to get desired result (at least doesn't show any color on touch event).
Thx in advance.

Comment: Have you read the page you are linking?

Comment: Surely I have read it

Comment: There's a "style the drawer" section with some promising suggestions.

Comment: I have read this, but didn't find anything please if u found something, let me know

Answer (score 0):

The shown issue is fixed in the latest version of the MaterialDrawer.

This was only a problem on Android 2.3. The Problem here was, that i did not set the background for the `ListView`, and set it transparent. On those Android versions this still causes some troubles.

Just update and it's fine.